# Python Requests Post login

Tags: python, html, post, python-requests, get

Yes, I know I'm green. I'm trying to learn how to POST into websites though I cannot seem pic the right fields to pass into the POST request.

Below you'll see the HTML for the site that I'm trying to grab everything from:

[HTML picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJiyq.png)

I've tried the following code to log into the website for Greetly but been having a hell of a time. I'm sure the values I'm passing must have the wrong keys but I can't seem to figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://app.greetly.com'
urlVisitorLog = 'https://app.greetly.com/locations/00001/check_in_records'
values = {
    'user[email]':'email',
    'user[password]':'password'
}

c = requests.Session()
results = c.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.content, 'html.parser')
key = soup.find(name="authenticity_token")
authenticity_token = key['value']

values["authenticity_token"] = authenticity_token

c.post(urlVisitorLog, headers= values)
r = c.get(urlVisitorLog)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

Also once I get the username and password I noticed the authenticity token isn't bound to a specific id but I also kind of need that login in order to parse through and see where that is.

Comment: There are a couple things which I found in your code, do try to analyze and sort them out:
1) Logging into websites usually takes a `post` command but here you are doing the `get` function of `requests`. 
2) While creating a `post` function, you don't need to do requests.Session().

Remove/edit these lines and see what happens.

Comment: Hey Esvin!
The only reason I was originally doing a get was to grab the authenticity token. After I grab that I pass the login values (as well as the authenticity token) into a post for the login. 
Should I be posting at the login page, and... I guess I'll have to test but can I grab the authenticity token from a post to the login page? 
I guess yeah you're right I'd have to pass the login into into the login page, if you have any info about all of this I'd be more than happy to take a look as well :)

Comment: Hey there!, instead of using `get` to grab the authenticity token( I'm guessing it's your api key)  why don't you try storing it as an environment variable and getting via the python `os` module? Or you could try storing it as a local variable i.e inside your program file? And yeah,  you have to use `post` to login into pages as that is easier to code. Happy to help!